# When to release a UIView that is removed from superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uiview, dealloc

I am creating a loading screen UIView which is added to a subview while some XML is parsed from some URL. Once the XML is returned, the loading screen is removed from its superview.

The question I have is **how should I release this object?**

In the code below, you'll see that I send `removeFromSuperview` to the loadingScreen, but I still have ownership of this object unless I release it. But, if I release it, there'll be nothing there to release in `viewdidUnload` and `dealloc`.

```
- (void)loadView {
  ...
  loadingScreen = [[LoadingScreen alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
  [self.view addSubview:loadingScreen]; //retain count = 2
}

-(void)doneParsing {
  ...
  [loadingScreen removeFromSuperview]; //retain count = 1
  [loadingScreen release]; //should i release the loading screen here?
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [loadingScreen release]; //if viewDidUnload is called AFTER doneParsing, this
                           //will cause an exception, but the app might crash before
                           //doneParsing is called, so i need something here
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [loadingScreen release]; //if i've already released the object, i can't release here
}
```

Comment: Actually I think I have solved this by releasing the loadingScreen after it is added as a subview and then removing the loadingScreen from the superview in doneParsing. I am not releasing the loadingScreen in viewDidUnload or dealloc.

Comment: This is correct. Give it to the superview and then release it. After that, it's not your responsibility any more and you can forget about it. The superview will release it when the superview is released itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you release loadingScreen, reset it to a nil value.

```
[loadingScreen release];
loadingScreen = nil;
```

[nil release] won't happen anything.